# JQuery autocomplete stopped working

Tags: jquery

My Jquery ui autocomplete feature stopped working when merging an application.

My libraries are (all scripts):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bubblepopup.v2.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-autocomplete/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-autocomplete/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-autocomplete/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.pack.js"></script>
```

And the code:

```
$(function () {
    function split(val) {
        return val.split(",\n");

    }

    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }

    $("#responsableUtu")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }




    })

    .autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {
            $.getJSON("username.html?startWith=" + extractLast(request.term),

            {

            }, response);
        },

        search: function () {
            // custom minLength
            var term = extractLast(this.value);
            if (term.length < 3) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        focus: function () {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(" ");
            return false;
        }


    });
});
```

Libs are found. What's wrong?

Comment: are you using fire bug ? if you are, use it for errors and post your error with your code.

Comment: Is there a way to track disabled and duplicate script libraries too with firebug?

Answer (score 0):

You're including the autocomplete's script four times (two times the uncompressed one, and one time the min and pack version), and you reincluding jQuery UI's modules when you've already included the whole library.

Try to replace your `<script />`s block with this:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bubblepopup.v2.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This should give you a "clean" environment (I used Google's CDN as I don't know what's in your files).

Does it resolve the problem?

Comment: My autocomplete depencies are ui.core, ui.widget and ui.position